When i open or create a new Project, the path is not the project directory Visual Studio ASP.NET Core 6
As the title says, when I open an existing project or create a new project in Visual Studio the default path open is not the project directory.
I only have tested with a console application project and ASP.NET Core Web API, both in .NET 6.
For example, in PowerShell I run dotnet watch and get a message

No project found in the directory 'C:\Users\User\source\repos\project'

and that's the default path used by Visual Studio, but, if i go to cd "project" A.K.A this route "C:\Users\User\source\repos\project\project", that's when the commands run like they should.
Also, when I install anything through NuGet Manager it says I installed something, but after I run something is just not installed, so I have to manually run dotnet add package "package".
I think this second error is because NuGet is trying to use the default path.
Hope this helps.

What is the directory you are sited? And by the way, what is the visual studio version?

You can take a look of my answer and try changing the working directory

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 17.7.6, the default open directory in one of my projects is "C:\Users\Gashe\source\repos\QuestPDF_Report_Sample>" and can't get it to run "dotnet watch" or "dotnet add package " without first "doing cd QuestPDF_Report_Sample", my route ending like this "C:\Users\Gashe\source\repos\QuestPDF_Report_Sample\QuestPDF_Report_Sample>", and to clarify, mi .csproj ends in this route "C:\Users\Gashe\source\repos\QuestPDF_Report_Sample\QuestPDF_Report_Sample\QuestPDF_Report_Sample.csproj"

You need to cd to the target directory to make it be the working directory.
In powershell, there is two commands needed:

The command to change the drive:

cd D:\


The command to change the directory:

cd 'somepath'

Or you can directly set the project like this in any directory:
dotnet watch --project 'C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\ConsoleApp9\ConsoleApp9.csproj'

for dotnet package install, you can directly use it like this in any directory:
dotnet add 'C:\Users\Administrator\source\repos\ConsoleApp9\ConsoleApp9.csproj' package Newtonsoft.Json

Take a look of the official documents:
dotnet watch
dotnet add package

I already do that, what i mean is, the default path when i open or create a new project should be right, but is not, i want to fix it, so i can normally use NuGet or other dotnet commands directly

@LittleCat27 Hi, have you place the solution and the project in the same directory?
